# Using R, return SQL results but not message from a stored proc

Tags: sql-server, r, stored-procedures, rodbc

Is there a way to mute a `print` statement that occurs within a stored procedure, without editing the procedure?

I run a SQL query using RODBC from with R. Other answers have addressed that `SET NOCOUNT ON` is often required in order to just return the Results of the query and not any Messages.

My issue is my query runs a stored proc which has some `print` statements in it, and `SET NOCOUNT ON` does not mute them. This means my R script returns `character(0)` when it's hitting that stored proc.

Is there a way to only return the Results and mute the stored proc's `print` statement?

My code is something like:

```
library(RODBC)

# SQL execution function
execSQL = function(sql){
  db=odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=<server>;database=<database>;trusted_connection=true') 
  on.exit(odbcClose(db))
  sqlQuery(db, sql)
}

# SQL Query
sqlfull <- "
  SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @MYVAR INT
  INSERT INTO @MYVAR (SELECT TOP 1 BLAH FROM MYTABLE)
  ;

  CREATE TABLE #TEMP (OUT1 INT, OUT2 FLOAT)
  INSERT INTO #TEMP (OUT1, OUT2)
  EXEC SP_MYPROC @MYVAR
  ;

  SET NOCOUNT OFF;
  SELECT * FROM #TEMP t1 
  JOIN OTHERTABLE t2 on t1.OUT1 = t2.OUT2"

# Cleanup query
sql <- gsub(pattern = '\n', replacement = " ", x = sqlfull)

# Execute SQL
SQLOutput <- execSQL(sql)

# Returns character(0)
```

It is important to note that this ran without issue prior until the stored proc had the print statement added. This SQL Query runs on SSMS without issue.

Comment: What does your code look like?  I've never had this problem and I use `sqlQuery` (see my answer below)

Comment: I've added an example template of my code and a note underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

I have print statements in my SQL stored procedures all the time.  This has always worked for me:

```
get_table_from_sql = function(sql) {
    conn <- RODBC::odbcConnect(dsn = "MYSQLSERVER")
    sql_data = RODBC::sqlQuery(conn, sql)
    RODBC::odbcClose(conn)
    return(sql_data)
}
```

where `MYSQLSERVER` is to be replaced by your own server name.  You'd call it like this:

```
get_table_from_sql("EXEC my_procedure")
```

Comment: Thanks lebelinoz. I've added my code which varies in only minor ways from yours. I included some of the specifics, such as the temp table usage and the variable setting, but I don't believe these are related to the issue, as 1) they ran fine before the sp had its print statements, and 2) running on SSMS the full query returns the results normally with the print statement in the messages tab. Suppressing the print has worked in the past, but I would like to leave the proc unedited if possible.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you might be doing too much inside your sql string.  Consider writing a stored procedure which encapsulates everything you need (including creating the #Temp table) and call that instead.

Comment: Unfortunately such a stored proc would have to call the offending stored proc anyway, so the print statement would still be returned.

Comment: In my experience, a simple called to a stored procedure (as in my example) would work even if the stored procedure has print statements.  What happens when you directly call `execSQL("EXEC SP_MYPROC n")`, where `n` is a number which will work with `SP_MYPROC`?

Comment: I wasn't able to try your suggestion as the proc ended up getting updated anyway and removed the print statements. I am still curious about this though and will try again when the opportunity arises and report back.